# Clear sheet button - Google Scripts

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I'm trying to clear a spreadsheet I have within Google. 
I'm using the following code but can't seem to get it to work. The button is there but it doesn't do anything and gives me the error of can't find menubutton.

```
var activeSS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var activeSh = activeSS.getActiveSheet();
var menubuttons = [ {name: 'Clear Sheet', functionName: 'Clearsheet'},]
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');

function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  ui.createMenu('Clear Sheet')
      .addItem('Clear Sheet', 'menubuttons')
      .addToUi();
}


function menubuttons() {

  ss.addMenu('Clearsheet', 'menubuttons'); 

// note you also have to have functions called clearRange1 and clearRange2     as list below
function Clearsheet() { //replace 'Sheet1' with your actual sheet name

      sheet.getRange('A7:I100').clearContent();
}
  }
```

Comment: This is the error I receive - Script function not found: menubuttons For more information, see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/menu#addItem(String,String)

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it!! - The ] was on the wrong line.. Took days to figure it out!

```
function onOpen() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var menubuttons = [ {name: "Clear Sheet", functionName: "clearRange1"},]
    ss.addMenu("Clear Sheet", (menubuttons)) ;
} 

function clearRange1() { 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  sheet.getRange('A8:I73').clearContent();
}
```